# Is there any maven phase to run the jar

Tags: java, ant, maven

In Ant, I can have a target named run to execute the jar with specified the classpath. I am wondering if maven has the similar phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Maven standard phase to run code.  [This page](http://cvs.peopleware.be/training/maven/maven2/buildLifecyclePhases.html) lists the standard Maven lifecycle phases.

If you want to go down the road of doing this yourself, [this section](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-custom-lifecycle.html) of the Maven book talks about adding custom phases.